# How to print 'ON' for once if at least 1 'ON' of last 5 (ON/OFF) status?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to see if machine is working or not. I made a circuit to see current on the cable but sometimes I see 'OFF' on the screen even machine does not stop. I decided to change code instead of the circuit. So I want to see 'ON' on the screen if there is 'ON' for once in the last 5 status.

My code is like below:

```
prev_Status = None

while True:
    if sensor > 1.60:
        Status = 'ON'
    else:
        Status = 'OFF'

    if Status != prev_Status:
        print("Status : {}".format(Status))
        prev_Status = Status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current implementation holds a single previous state and cannot do what you want. A [`deque()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is a nice fit for this task: it can be limited to a maximum size and it has fast appends and pops:

```
from collections import deque

prev_statuses = deque([], maxlen=5)

while True:
    if sensor > 1.6:
        status = 'ON'
    else:
        status = 'OFF'

    prev_statuses.append(status)

    if 'ON' in prev_statuses:
        print("Status: ON")
    else:
        print("Status: OFF")
```

If you want to be fancy about it, store the boolean value of the test in the status queue and use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
from collections import deque

prev_statuses = deque([], maxlen=5)

while True:    
    prev_statuses.append(sensor > 1.6)

    if any(prev_statuses):
        print("Status: ON")
    else:
        print("Status: OFF")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to keep track of the last 5 statuses maybe? (Untested)

```
prev_Status = ['None']

while True:
    if sensor > 1.60:
        Status = 'ON'
    else:
        Status = 'OFF'

    if Status not in prev_Status:
        print("Status : {}".format(Status))

    prev_Status.append(Status)
    if len(prev_Status) > 5:
        del prev_Status[0]
```

also as a convention you don't need to underscore **AND** camelcase, use either `prev_status` or `prevStatus` (I forget which is more pythonic)